# How do i make Bootstrap columns responsive on all devices?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently developing a Login/Register page but I need help with the columns. The page currently looks like this on desktop 1920x180: http://prntscr.com/cl4ms8

I am using `<div class="col-xs-6">` on both of the forms so they are evenly split on the page. How would I go across making it so it will be responsive on all devices as it currently looks like this on an iPhone 6: http://prntscr.com/cl4ndb

Comment: We need the code to help you solve the problem, please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Zac, Well the bootstrap is doing what it's supposed to do. Basically what you've said is. I want this div to take up 50% of the parent element on all devices larger then xs (0px). What I would suggest is that you change the class to: `<div class="col-sm-6">` or if that is not enough `col-md-6`. (I want this element 50% width on devices larger then sm/md) Hope you found this useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You elements with the `col-xx-n` classes need to be children or descendants of an element with the class `container-fluid`.

So, this will be responsive:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-4">This div takes up 1/3 of the available width on a desktop</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">This div takes up 2/3 of the available width on a desktop</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Bootstrap ships with 4 tiers of grids, which have class prefixes of;

- .col-xs- , (<768px)
- .col-sm- , (≥768px)
- .col-md- , (≥992px)
- .col-lg- , (≥1200px)

If you've applied a column class of "col-xs-6" what you are saying is that from 0px to 767px i want this column to be 50% of the containers width. And unless you add another class for the next grid tier, it will continue to be 50% of the parent on wider screens as well. So not only up to 768px but beyond unless you add another class.

Your problem here is that most mobiles are simply too narrow to show two columns for this purpose. So change `"col-xs-6"` to `"col-xs-12"`. And add "col-sm-6" as well.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
```

That will mean that from 768px and up, the columns wil be 50%.

The reason why the layout looks broken though is probably because your input's have a width or min-width that is greater than the 50% width of the container and are therefore wider than the column grid they are nested in.

Answer (score 4):

Use bootstap's class `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` for both main div of login and registration is and  you can reffer the site http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

**example:**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">///or container   
         <div id="login" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            ///your login form 
            </div>
        <div id="registration" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            ///your registration form 
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a bootstrap grid: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/ (that's the v4 documentation, but v3 (the standard) works the same and v4 documentation is better). See also w3schools' tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp